# Electron/React: How to use IPC to run Global Shortcut uninterrupted

Tags: reactjs, electron, ipc

Pretty new in the world of Electron but I want to make a little application for myself.

The gist of my app is as follows: because I work in a lot of different applications the more complex shortcuts are often forgotten when I haven't dabbled in said application for a while. So, I want to make an Electron app that shows me a bunch of icons that I can press on my touch monitor and then execute the command for me. Kind of like a virtual stream deck.

So far I have the application running with Electron,Webpack and React and I managed to set up a working IPC connection between React and Main.js portion.

```
/* React App.js */
const handleHotKeyClick = (hotkey: string) =>{
  ipcRenderer.send(CATCH_ON_MAIN, hotkey);
 }
```

And in Main.js I tried to directly fire the globalShortcut from within the ipcMain like so:

```
ipcMain.on(CATCH_ON_MAIN, (event, arg) => {
     console.log('Incoming command', arg);
     globalShortcut.register(arg, () => {
        console.log('ipc pressed!')
     })
 });
```

This doesn't work. It seems globalShortcut only works from the App.ready.

So, how can I set a global shortcut like this using the ipc communication I set up here.
Secondly, I noticed if I hardcode the shorthut handler in the App.Ready, it catches it, but doesn't continue doing what the command should do. It prevents the default behavior. Is there a way around this?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you registering a callback `globalShortcut.register` every time when `CATCH_ON_MAIN` callback is executed? Moreover it will only register the callback and will not run the callback. Ideally you should register callback only once

If you want to execute a callback in main process when any keyboard short cut is pressed, then you can write as below in `main` process and no need to do write anything in `renderer` process. Refer [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/global-shortcut)

```
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  // Register a 'Control+X' shortcut listener.
  const ret = globalShortcut.register('Control+X', () => {
    console.log('Control+X is pressed');
  });

  if (!ret) {
    console.log('registration failed');
  }

  // Check whether a shortcut is registered.
  console.log(globalShortcut.isRegistered('Control+X'));
});
```

if you want to execute a callback in main process when any button is pressed. then do write as below.

```
//in renderer process,
const handleHotKeyClick = (hotkey: string) =>{
  ipcRenderer.send(CATCH_ON_MAIN, hotkey);
 }
```

---

```
//in main process
ipcMain.on(CATCH_ON_MAIN, (event, arg) => {
     console.log('Incoming command', arg);
 });
```